# Spark ignores parameter spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat

Tags: apache-spark

I have an issue with spark 2.4.7. I run a job that reads table in database and generates parquet file. It should contain timestamp and some decimal parameters. By default in parquet file timestamp was generated as int96. Once I set `spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat     false`, Spark started to write timestamp as a number.
But for some reason setting `spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat     false` does not change Spark vehavior with decimals. But as per documentation it should work:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html
spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat     false
spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType   TIMESTAMP_MILLIS

spark.master  yarn
```

Output:

```
timestamp = 1657498168000
...
rate = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAiVRAA==
```

What can affect this parameter? I have tried to set it in spark-submit config, but same result - no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read Koedlt's advice and tried to dig into Spark code as well. And I found the reason of this behaviour.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/928f518574ea755b5ae7ec028354450b7d1ca7f4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetSchemaConverter.scala , spark will use legacy format (FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY) if number of decimal digits is more than a limit (18 digits).

```
  // ======================
  // Decimals (legacy mode)
  // ======================

  // Spark 1.4.x and prior versions only support decimals with a maximum precision of 18 and
  // always store decimals in fixed-length byte arrays.  To keep compatibility with these older
  // versions, here we convert decimals with all precisions to `FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY` annotated
  // by `DECIMAL`.
  case DecimalType.Fixed(precision, scale) if writeLegacyParquetFormat =>
    Types
      .primitive(FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY, repetition)
      .as(LogicalTypeAnnotation.decimalType(scale, precision))
      .length(Decimal.minBytesForPrecision(precision))
      .named(field.name)
  // ========================
  // Decimals (standard mode)
  // ========================

  // Uses INT32 for 1 <= precision <= 9
  case DecimalType.Fixed(precision, scale)
      if precision <= Decimal.MAX_INT_DIGITS && !writeLegacyParquetFormat =>
    Types
      .primitive(INT32, repetition)
      .as(LogicalTypeAnnotation.decimalType(scale, precision))
      .named(field.name)

  // Uses INT64 for 1 <= precision <= 18
  case DecimalType.Fixed(precision, scale)
      if precision <= Decimal.MAX_LONG_DIGITS && !writeLegacyParquetFormat =>
    Types
      .primitive(INT64, repetition)
      .as(LogicalTypeAnnotation.decimalType(scale, precision))
      .named(field.name)

  // Uses FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY for all other precisions
  case DecimalType.Fixed(precision, scale) if !writeLegacyParquetFormat =>
    Types
      .primitive(FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY, repetition)
      .as(LogicalTypeAnnotation.decimalType(scale, precision))
      .length(Decimal.minBytesForPrecision(precision))
      .named(field.name)
```

So I just realized that I have numbers more than 18 digits. Here is example of an SQL that creates a table that spark job reads:

```
column1                  Nullable( Decimal (38, 8)),
```

Once I changed it to Decimal (16, 8), I got what I wanted:

```
column1 = 1001850000000000
column2 = 954506506270500
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at version 2.4.7's way of reading in the `spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat` in [SQLConf.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.7/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L441), you see that it gets read into the `PARQUET_WRITE_LEGACY_FORMAT` value of the `SQLConf` object with a default value that is `false`.

You seem to be using the default value, so that would explain why you see no difference in behaviour. Try setting it to `true` to see if you see desirable behaviour? Of course I'm not sure what you really want as output but I would expect some different behaviour.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: If you're interested in how and where these parameters affect the writing of parquet, the `SparkToParquetSchemaConverter` class is interesting. Particularly lines [372 to 448](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.7/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetSchemaConverter.scala#L372). You'll see which config has impact on what type of value for timestamps and decimals.

Comment: I tried to set this parameter to true in config and in spark-submit, but no see difference. Will try to play with configs more :(

Comment: I've added some more info that might give you more insights onto how these configs should impact the behaviour. Hopefully you'll find it! :)

Comment: Hey. I just found the root cause. Your answer was definitely helpful and helped me. I have posted answer. In short: I do have numbers with more digits that spark accepts for int64 and it writes such numbers as byte array.

Comment: Awesome, happy I was able to help!